# CDVPlugin class ChildBrowserCommand (pluginName: ChildBrowserCommand) does not exist

Tags: iphone, cordova, salesforce, phonegap-plugins

I have created a PhoneGap based application and included the same code I have downloaded from this link: [Building PhoneGap Mobile Applications Powered by Database.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Building_PhoneGap_Mobile_Applications_Powered_by_Database.com)

When I run the app I am able to see login screen. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

When I click on Login button nothing is happening, I am in the same page. I have already included my cosumer key in `salesforceWrapper.js` file like this:

```
function SalesforceWrapper() {
    /* AUTHENTICATION PARAMETERS */
    this.loginUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
    this.clientId = 'sadsadasdadadasdasdasdsadasdas.dsddsd_sdsds.dsdsdsdsdsds';
    this.redirectUri = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success';

    /* CLASS VARIABLES */
    this.cb = ChildBrowser.install(); //ChildBrowser in PhoneGap
    this.client = new forcetk.Client(this.clientId, this.loginUrl); //forceTk client instance

    this.init();
}
```

Why am I unable to redirect to salesforece login page? Here is the console output:

```
2012-06-25 16:20:53.023 J[2396:13403] Opening Url : https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?display=touch&response_type=token&client_id=sadsadasdadadasdasdasdsadasdas.dsddsd_sdsds.dsdsdsdsdsds&redirect_uri=https%3A//login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success
2012-06-25 16:20:53.024 J[2396:13403] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Application tried to present modally an active controller <MainViewController: 0x9a67dc0>.
2012-06-25 16:20:53.034 J[2396:13403] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?display=touch&response_type=token&client_id=sadsadasdadadasdasdasdsadasdas.dsddsd_sdsds.dsdsdsdsdsds&redirect_uri=https%3A//login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success'
```

Added ChildBrowserCommand and ChildBrowser fields to Cordova.plist.
[image]

Included the script file path in Index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
```

and here is my Xcode project screenshot:

[image]

I have solved `CDVPlugin` reference issue and got the `WebKit discarded an uncaught exception` issue. How can I solve this?

Solved it by adding extra parameter to ExternalHosts in Crodova.plist.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have you edited the Cordova.plist file to include the mapping required for the ChildBrowser plugin?
- Have you included the .h .m source code for the ChildBrowser plugin correctly in your project?
- Have you included the childbrowser.js file, and loaded it into your index.html file?

It's normally one of these issues that causes the problem.

Comment: Yes. I have added 2 fields (ChildBrowser, ChildBrowserCommand) to the plist.

Comment: And included childbrowser.js in index.html also.

Comment: I have placed ChildBrowser files in Plugins folder. Do you think that would be the problem. I have edited my post please check it once.

Comment: Ben Clayton Do you know how can I solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191311/oauth2-issue-in-salesforce-phonegap-iphone-application-remote-access-applicatio

Comment: I'm glad you sorted the original issue. Can't help you with the oauth issue though sorry!

Comment: I have fixed it. I need to click on Done button. I didn't do that, I thought it will automatically redirect me to next screen. Same is happening in iOS 4.3 Simulator but not working in iOS 5.1 simulator.

Comment: may be because of browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that is facing this issue,

The problem is perhaps due to the fact the event handlers are not properly bound. - Or bound more than once (most probably).

While a patch has to be done on the plugin code to prevent it from trying to bind more than once, a simple way to prevent this happening is to use a delegated event handler in jQuery and ensure the event is bound to the target exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else having this issue on IOS 5, the issue is that Childbrowser is trying to displaye twice which causes the error.  One solution is to throw a try catch around the display code.

i.e.  change this (ChildBrowserCommand.m -> showWebPage)

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
CDVViewController* cont = (CDVViewController*)[ super viewController ];
childBrowser.supportedOrientations = cont.supportedOrientations;
childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[ cont presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];
#endif
```

To This:

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
CDVViewController* cont = (CDVViewController*)[ super viewController ];
childBrowser.supportedOrientations = cont.supportedOrientations;
childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
@try {
    [ cont presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];
}@catch(NSException * e){
    NSLog(@"ALready visible");
}
#endif
```

Comment: if(childBrowser.presentingViewController == nil){
        [ cont presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];
    }